# Removing .edmx from my project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, unity-container, repository-pattern

I am using Code First with existing DB- Entity Framework 4.1, In my project i added .edmx file and generated schema, views stored procedures everything is working perfect, everything is in production.

My problem is here

```
1- I moved my .edmx file,.tt to other project
2- Removed from working project
3- Copy all schema,view,DBContext everything related to .edmx generated to folder called Entities.
4- Removed matadata information from connection string which is in web.config
```

After that i am not able to run the project error coming error is

```
System.Data.DataException was unhandled by user code
  Message=An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
       at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
       at QTrac.DAL.RepositoryBase`1.Get(Expression`1 filter, Func`2 orderBy, Nullable`1 take, String includeProperties, Boolean tracking) in D:\QTrack\Project-NewQTrac\QTrac\QTrac.DAL\RepositoryBase.cs:line 39
       at QTrac.DAL.EquipStateRepository.GetEquipStates(Nullable`1 active) in D:\QTrack\Project-NewQTrac\QTrac\QTrac.DAL\EquipStateRepository.cs:line 25
       at QTrac.BLL.AssetManagementService.GetEquipStates(Nullable`1 active) in D:\QTrack\Project-NewQTrac\QTrac\BL\AssetManagementService.cs:line 68
       at QTrac.Web.Controllers.AssetManagementController.Grid_PopulateEquipmentStateCombo() in D:\QTrack\Project-NewQTrac\QTrac\QTrac.Web\Controllers\AssetManagementController.cs:line 135
       at QTrac.Web.Controllers.AssetManagementController.Detail() in D:\QTrack\Project-NewQTrac\QTrac\QTrac.Web\Controllers\AssetManagementController.cs:line 38
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException: System.Data.EntityException
       Message=The underlying provider failed on Open.
       Source=System.Data.Entity
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
            at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
            at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
            at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
            at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
            at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
            at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
            at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
            at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
            at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModelHash()
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata)
            at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass5.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__3()
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
       InnerException: System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException
            Message=Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool.
            Source=System.Transactions
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.ProxyException(COMException comException)
                 at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[] propagationToken)
                 at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEPromote(InternalTransaction tx)
                 at System.Transactions.TransactionStateDelegatedBase.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx)
                 at System.Transactions.EnlistableStates.Promote(InternalTransaction tx)
                 at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote()
                 at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction transaction)
                 at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetExportCookie(Transaction transaction, Byte[] whereabouts)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.GetTransactionCookie(Transaction transaction, Byte[] whereAbouts)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Activate(Transaction transaction)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
                 at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
            InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
                 Message=The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D024)
                 Source=System.Transactions
                 ErrorCode=-2147168220
                 StackTrace:
                      at System.Transactions.Oletx.IDtcProxyShimFactory.ReceiveTransaction(UInt32 propgationTokenSize, Byte[] propgationToken, IntPtr managedIdentifier, Guid& transactionIdentifier, OletxTransactionIsolationLevel& isolationLevel, ITransactionShim& transactionShim)
                      at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[] propagationToken)
                 InnerException:
```

Please tell me what is this issue and please tell me solution.

Thanks

Comment: What does the InnerException contains?

Answer (score 0):

Since the .edmx file is really just an xml file, I suggest opening the file in notepad and checking to make sure the references are pointing to the new project instead of the older one.

Comment: edmx file is working fine in new project, but my project from where i deleted that project is not working error u can see.

Comment: Are you still referencing it somewhere in the old project? Try removing all of the library references for the entity framework, that way the compiler will tell you if you were referencing the edmx anywhere in the code.